# keep getting error message when trying to read json from s3

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-3.7

I keep getting this error in my lambda function:

`{"errorMessage": "module initialization error"}`

This happens when i try to turn the following string containing json data into a json dictionary object within python.

```
"{\n\"main\": {\n  \"PART_NAME\": \"Genuine Cardboard Honda Wing\",\n  \"BRAND\": \"Honda\",\n  \"MJR_CAT\": \"Aero\",\n  \"CAT\": \"Rear Wing\",\n  \"SUB_CAT\": \"NA\",\n  \"Power_Increase\": \"0\"\n},\n\"forza\":\n{\n  \"power\": \"[0, True]\",\n  \"Torque\": \"[0, True]\",\n  \"Traction\": \"[50, True]\",\n  \"Handling\": \"[100, True]\",\n  \"Breaking\": \"[40, True]\"\n},\n\"custom\": {\n\"length\": 120,\n\"car max height[m]\": 2,\n\"RICER RANK\": -10\n\n}\n"
```

Here is my code to replicate this error:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
result = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=FILE_TO_READ) 
text = result['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
text = json.load(text)
print(text)
```

without the `print(text)` it produces that string above.

Thanks :)

Here is the full lambda function (though not commented) if you are interested.

```
import json
import boto3
print('got this far')
BUCKET = '******'
FILE_TO_READ = 'example_honda_wing.json'
client = boto3.client('s3')
result = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=FILE_TO_READ) 
text = result['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
#text = str(text).replace("\n","")
#text = text.replace('\"',' ')

#text = json.load(text)
print(text) # Use your desired JSON Key for your value 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return text
```

Comment: you should write the code inside the `lambda_handler` def

Comment: for example :https://stackoverflow.com/a/58597953/9931092

Comment: @AmitBaranes That dosent work either

Comment: Can you share example_honda_wing.json?

Comment: Instead of `json.load(text)`, try using `json.loads(text)`, since you have already done a `read()` on the result.