# boto3: file content length is right but the body is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a file of size 4.4MB in an S3 bucket and when I try to download it through boto3, the content length I see in the object description is right but the body of the object is empty. Any ideas why that is happening?

```
s3 = session.client('s3')    
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
obj['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['content-length'] ## this returns 4598667
obj['ContentLength'] ## this returns 4598667 as well
obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8') ## this returns ''
```

Comment: What's the type of content? json?csv ?

Comment: it is a csv file

Comment: Take a look at my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58597953/9931092

Comment: Wow, this is incredible, it helped, thanks so much! I wish this information existed somewhere in the AWS official documentation (maybe it does, but I could not find it). I tried reading a python script (.py file) as well from the same bucket while debugging the problem and I had a similar issue for that file as well. Looks like reading the file line by line explicitly is a generic solution. Why is that the case, though? Why does not streaming handle this already?

Comment: Sure, let me post it as an answer for future questions

Comment: By the way, feel free to upvote the answer that solved your issue :)

Comment: That's not what I would expect and it is not what I see. The response is a long (4.4MB) string with `\r\n` separated lines of CSV content, as expected. How are you validating the result of `obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: I just do `print(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))` and it returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as mentioned in comments, The key is to use `csv.reader()` and `obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()` ( The full code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597384/fail-to-get-csv-from-s3-and-convert-it-with-python/58597953#58597953).)

> Why does not streaming handle this already?

**About csv.reader (From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html?highlight=csv)):**

> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given
>   csvfile. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator
>   protocol and returns a string each time its **next**() method is
>   called — file objects and list objects are both suitable. If csvfile
>   is a file object, it should be opened with newline=''.
>
> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a **list of strings**. No
>   automatic data type conversion is performed unless the
>   QUOTE_NONNUMERIC format option is specified

With that been said, we must iterate over the return data from csv.reader in order to see the actual lines.

Code snippet example:

```py
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
         print(', '.join(row))
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Comment: Hi Amit, it's not clear to me that this explains what's actually going on. Certainly if you want to split a string that contains multiple lines of CSV and consume it as a CSV then you can call `splitlines()` on the original string and then use with `csv.reader()` but that requires you to have the body of the CSV file in a string in the first place, which is what you get from `obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')`. The OP's issue suggest that the body content had not been streamed and decoded (he claims to have an empty string).

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the reason why we see an empty string before calling `splitlines()` is not clear in the answer.